# Not able to run sample Jasper iReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have created a sample report and trying to Load it from jFrame button click.

Code:

```
try {

         String IP = "192.168.1.123";
         String DataBase = "traders_bikri";
         String ID = "root";
         String Password = "PASSWORD";

         Connection con1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + IP + "/" + DataBase + "", ID, Password);

         String report = "N:\\projectTest\\src\\projectTest\\report1.jasper";

         try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
         } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
         }                 
         JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(report);    
         JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, null, con1);    
         JasperViewer.viewReport(jp, false);    
         con1.close();

      } catch (JRException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();    
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
      } catch (SQLException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(ReportLoaderForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
```

And here is from the output window.

```
run:
Sat Jul 22 20:25:36 IST 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.<clinit>(JRLoader.java:81)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRPropertiesUtil.loadProperties(JRPropertiesUtil.java:102)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.DefaultJasperReportsContext.initProperties(DefaultJasperReportsContext.java:99)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.DefaultJasperReportsContext.<init>(DefaultJasperReportsContext.java:76)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.DefaultJasperReportsContext.<clinit>(DefaultJasperReportsContext.java:59)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.getDefaultInstance(JasperCompileManager.java:200)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:575)
    at ireportsdemo.ReportLoaderForm.jButton1ActionPerformed(ReportLoaderForm.java:96)
    at ireportsdemo.ReportLoaderForm.access$000(ReportLoaderForm.java:25)
    at ireportsdemo.ReportLoaderForm$1.actionPerformed(ReportLoaderForm.java:50)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 46 more
```

Please guide  to findout where is the problem.
Also, when I am previewing the report in iReports design and preview, its loading well in IDE as well as in Internet Explorer.

I had to use try-catch block twice because I IDe forced me to do that.

Comment: Where is your port 3306 in con1 ? Below is valid to connect using java jdbc:mysql://IP:PORT/databaseName

Comment: I tried, even this didn't work. 
 String IP = "192.168.1.123:3306";

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory Try to fix this issue.

Comment: Several libs were missing, added them all, one-by-one, now this

WT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ModuleNode.getStarImports()Ljava/util/List;

Comment: Solved, was having two different Jar's for groove. Thanks for the guidance.